# php как apache2 настройка прав доступа

Tags: php, apache, nginx, cgi

Надоело редактировать права на libapache2modphp , вот в чем собственно вопрос , можно ли на ubuntu 16.04 заставить php и apache работать от имени пользователя , а не от имени самого себя , чтобы не приходилось каждый раз для всех файлов задавать права чтение/запись , да и когда php создает файлы от себя он по дефаулту дает права только www.

Или единственный способ это переход на PHP FPM + nginx ?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_privileges.html#vhostuser

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать mpm_itk. В Debian и Ubuntu есть соотв. пакет. Для RHEL-based систем можно поставить заголовочные файлы Apache и собрать ручками (в сети есть готовые spec для этого).